# <urlopen error [Errno 11001]: getaddrinfo failed>

Tags: python

Could not connect to IP power. Perhaps the selecting of your proxy server in Internet Explorer are incorrect. Sending request to IP Power :http<...>

## Need help regarding this issue

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have provided an incorrect address to urlopen, otherwise there is a problem with your connection.Check these and if you couldn't resolve it, please update your question with your code.